# sort data in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS...I created a filter on an output data. Next I need to sort those array data based on a dropdown selected item. I am not getting it.The filter processing is done in the 3rd directive. Any help is appreciated.

```
 $scope.options=[
              {label: 'Name', value:1,submenu:null},
              {label: 'Age', value:2,submenu:null},
              {label: 'Country', value:3,submenu:[
                      {label:'India',value:1},
                      {label:'China',value:2},
                      {label:'Singapore',value:3},
                      {label:'London',value:4}
                  ]}
          ];

 <select ng-model="model1" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
        </select>
```

here is the plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/BFEJQo8Zp2eukdgP9BKM?p=preview

Comment: I didnt understand what you expecting ?

Comment: I created a form first and submitted the data . I retrieved the data and displayed on the form and created a filter based on gender.The filter is also working and getting the filtered data. Next I need to sort this filtered data based on a selected item from a drop down list.this list contains Name,age and country which in turn is a list of 4 country names.

Comment: I used three directives and a service. three html files for creating,displaying form and displaying filtered data.

Comment: what you mean by asking "Next I need to sort this filtered data based on a selected item from a drop down list"

Comment: Next I m trying to do that sorting...thats wht i meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a custom ordering in ng-repeat.

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDViYGitGKb9bXVyJGLS?p=preview)**

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in details | orderBy : sortingOrder : reverse" ng-show="showResults">
    {{detail.Fname | uppercase}}
    {{detail.Lname}}
    {{detail.age}}
    {{detail.sex}}
    {{detail.place}}
</div>
```

**script**

```
  $scope.search = function() {
    $scope.reverse = '';
    $scope.showResults = true;
    if ($scope.model1.label === 'Age') {
      $scope.sortingOrder = 'age';
    } else if ($scope.model1.label === 'Name') {
      $scope.sortingOrder = 'Fname';
    } else if ($scope.model1.label === 'Country') {
      $scope.sortingOrder = 'place';
    }
     else if ($scope.model1.label === 'Gender') {
       console.log($scope.user.sex1);

     if($scope.user.sex1 === 'male')
     {
       $scope.reverse = true;
     }
     else if($scope.user.sex1 === 'female')
     {
      $scope.reverse = false;
     }
      $scope.sortingOrder = 'sex';
    }
  };
```